# complete a table with data from an other one

Tags: sql, oracle9i

I have two tables `A(column1,column2)` and `B(column1,column2)`.

How  to ensure that a value from A(column1) is not contained within B(column1) and insert it in this column.

My Query will be like this :

```
insert into B.column1 values()  
 where
...
```

I want to complete B.column1 with data from A.column1

What should i  put in the `where` clause ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Insert Into B(column1)
Select A.Column1
From A
Where A.Column1 not in (Select Column1 From B)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use MINUS command and select all rows from A(column1) which are not in B(column1) and then SELECT INTO result into B table.

Answer (score 1):

```
insert into B
select a.column1, a.column2 from a
left join b
on a.column1 = b.column1
where b.column1 is null
```

Comment: It appears that this is not working in Oracle 9i..It gives me the error 'Keyword VALUES absent' How can I deal with this ?

Comment: @mounaim: 9i does not support the modern style explicit `JOIN` syntax (see: another reason why you shouldn't use an outdated version)